# Keyword spotting using HTK

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, htk, keyword-spotting

Recently I've focused on a project to implement a keyword spotting system. I've used HTK for speech recognition earlier. Now I want to know is it possible to implement my keyword spotter using HTK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speech recognition and keyword spotting are quite related problems.

For HTK one of the two solutions is possible:

1. build a word-loop grammar with a list of words you want to search, a garbage and a silence unit. See HBuild in HTKbook for details
2. do a conventional speech decoding, which produces a word lattice (.slf in HTK). Then convert it in a consensus network (a sausage) with, for example [lattice-tool](http://www.speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/manpages/lattice-tool.1.html), and search the words that have a score above some threshold

Comment: I have read the HBuild but find nothing abut my purpose. So I searched the web about how to create wordloop. But now I dont know what I should do.

Comment: If your keyword list is not too large, you can build a network as described [here](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/ln/LabROSA/doc/HTKBook21/node133.html). You should also add in the network garbage and silence units. If using HTK is not obligatory, it can probably be easier for you to use [KWS from Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid)